# Crear un sistema de vidas en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando crear un juego en php donde haya un sistema de vidas en que las vayas perdiendo si elegís la opción incorrecta.
El problema es que no se cómo empezar.

Intenté crear una función con la variable `$vidas` pero no puedo avanzar.
Ahí dejo el código:

```
$vidas = 3;

function wrong($vidas){
    $vidas --1;
}

echo foreach ($vidas as $vida) {
    wrong($vidas);
}

?>
```

Comment: y cual es la duda concreta? sino mejoras tu pregunta es dificil entender que requieres

Comment: Cómo crear una función donde apretar un botón reste una vida.

Comment: para eso necesitas manipular un elemento del DOM en este caso un botón con JavaScript y mandar el valor a PHP para que lo use en la función y reste un punto

Comment: Lo que busco es saber cómo sería la función, no la parte de javascript

Comment: algo así $vidas = $vidas - 1;

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es una función que reste uno a la variable vidas, podría ser algo así:

```
<?
$vidas = 3;

function wrong($vidas){
    $vidas--;
    return $vidas;
}

    echo wrong($vidas);

?>
```

Esto en si lo que hace es:

1. Crea la función `worng()` y dentro de ella decrementa en 1 el
   valor de la variable pasada.
2. Retorna el valor de dicha variable.
3. Imprime el valor de la variable pasada, decrementada en 1.

Un saludo !

Comment: Fua, ahí lo voy a probar, muchas gracias Dismark!

Comment: Si lo hace. Copia la función y pegala en php, te muestra en echo cómo la variable vida baja hasta 1

Comment: tienes razón @AlexFath no habia visto bien la función saludos

Answer (score -3):

```
$pulse = true;
$vidas = 3; 

function wrong($vidas){ 
       $vidas = $vidas - 1;
       Return ($vidas);
}

Function doc($respuesta){
    If(!$respuesta){
        wrong($vidas);
        If($vidas==0){
               $pulse=false;
        }
    }else{
        Echo "Cuidado!!";
    }
}

While($pulse){
        El juego aqui
        doc(respuesta);
}
Echo "Game Over";
```

Comment: donde has visto que esto funcione? `$vidas --1`

Comment: Esa es la parte de la pregunta que no edité

Comment: sin embargo la idea de aportar una respuesta es colocar la solución al problema amigo, por favor revisa [answer]

Comment: Estas muy aburrido?.

Comment: te lo edite para que no me retes de nuevo. ;)